# hstore operator precedence changed in between versions

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I found that this query:

```
SELECT properties->'somekey' IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'someValue' FROM myTable;
```

does work in PostgreSQL 9.5, but not in 9.4, it gives this error:

> ERROR: operator does not exist: hstore -> boolean

So, apprently the operator precedende of the `->` operator changed between versions. Thing is, I cannot find this (or even what the precedence *should* be) in the docs.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Comment: Although the hstore operator is not explicitly mentioned, see the comment at the end of the page: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE The [release notes for 9.5](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-5.html) also contain "*Adjust operator precedence to match the SQL standard*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so... according to this list, the behaviour of 9.4 is a bug?

Comment: Yes. Does the old behaviour look sane to you?

Answer (score 1):

I was puzzled briefly by this same error message. The issue is that Postgres first evaluates `'somekey' IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'somevalue'` and then uses the boolean produced from that statement as the key to find within `properties`, thus producing the error. You simply need to change

`SELECT properties->'somekey' IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'someValue' FROM myTable;`

to

`SELECT (properties->'somekey') IS NOT DISTINCT FROM 'someValue' FROM myTable;`

so that the code evaluates acccording to "the SQL standard".